# List all PVCs of an Openshift cluster

Tags: openshift, persistent-storage, openshift-client-tools

How to list from the commandline, all PVCs of an Openshift cluster ?

From my understanding, the scope of PVCs is the namespace/project, *in* which it was created.
Listing the PVCs implies being connected (*using*) or at least mentioning the namespace.
The best I came up with is :

`$ for i in $(oc get project -o name|cut -d"/" -f 2);do echo "Project: $i";oc get pvc -n $i;done`

Is there a better/cleaner/quickier way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an admin, try running:

```
oc get pvc --all-namespaces
```

Comment: When not admin, run just `oc get pvc`